# How to create custom column in SiteUserInfoList in SharePoint Online and access the same using CSOM/JSOM.

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom

My requirement is to maintain a flag value (eg., 1. whether logged in user subscribed or not 2.whether logged in user voted or not 3. etc.,) for each users in our org, so I planned to make use of SiteUserInfoList, having separate column for each flags. 
Can anyone help on creating (using CSOM/JSOM) custom column on SiteUserInfoList in SharePoint online and accessing the same using CSOM/JSOM? Alternate for using SiteUserInfoList also fine. 
Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a column in **SiteUserInfoList** but the best practice will be using a separate list for managing these types of information.

## Tips: Using REST API

*End-point*

```
{your site}/_api/web/SiteUserInfoList/Fields
```

*Request Body*

```
{
  "__metadata": {
    "type": "SP.Field"
  },
  "Title": "Is Subscribed", //Your field name
  "FieldTypeKind": 8, // For boolean it is 8
  "TypeAsString": "Boolean",
  "TypeDisplayName": "Yes/No"
}
```

Make a **POST** request to the above endpoint. You can use my [tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd) to do this.

[image]

*Get All users from **SiteUserInfoList***

```
{your site url}/_api/web/SiteUserInfoList/Items
```

Make a **GET** request to the above endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can - but you should not modify `SiteUserInfoList`.
What you should do - if this is a setting that is needed across all users - is to add a [new property to the user-profile](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Add-and-edit-user-profile-properties-85091402-737f-4bb9-99a7-bc5f194502a8).

Comment: Thank you. This is for specific site collection, I decided not to change at User Profile. Finally decided to put it in separate list.!!